# How to open encrypted PDF file on Android?

Tags: android, pdf, android-pdf-api

I'm using [JoanZapata/android-pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) library to open PDF file. But there is no option to open encrypted PDF file. Are there any other libraries to open PDF files or maybe it is possible with `JoanZapata/android-pdfview`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library like [RadaeePDF](http://www.radaeepdf.com/download) and open the file using the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
int result = doc.Open(path, password);
```